# C++ anonymous struct as std::map value

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, stl, std

I am using Visual Studio 2019 std:c++ 17 which supports anonymous struct, f.e.

```
struct S 
{ 
  struct { int i; };
};
```

However, the following code has compile errors.

```
map<int, struct { int i; }> m;
```

Can I use anonymous struct as value type of std::map?

Comment: Why would you wanna do that?

Comment: I have trouble naming...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anonymous structure is a structure that is defined within another class (structure). So you can not use such a structure inside a container because in this case it will not be an anonymous structure but will be just an unnamed structure.

In this record (that is incorrect)

```
map<int, struct { int i; }> m;
```

there is no anonymous structure. There is an attempt to use an unnamed structure.

You could write for example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    using  S = struct { int i; };
    std::map<int, S> m;
}
```

But as I said there is no anonymous structure.

Here is the definition of the notion anonymous structure (the C Standard, 6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers)

> 13 **An unnamed member of structure type** with no tag is called an
>   anonymous structure;

Comment: Thanks to your answer. Hoping C++ can support it sooner.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it directly, but indirectly, either

```
struct { int i; } s;
std::map<int, decltype(s)> a;
```

or

```
using MyType = struct { int i; };
std::map<int, MyType> b;
```

but note that `a` and `b` will be of different type. `decltype(s)` is not the same type as `MyType`.

Comment: Thanks to your answer, but both require naming. :(

Comment: @eihero technically the struct is still unnamed. The first example has a variable of unnamed type and the second one is an alias to an unnamed type. But yes, you need a name somewhere.